# Expandable listview not set the group item properly

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I created a custom expandable List View in android. When I run the application, the group lists are arrange randomly but not how I arranged the lists in the custom adapter. How can I make it to follow my arrangement when I run the application?

Comment: post your code so i get the well idea